# Is there any hadith that masturbation will cause pregnant hands in the afterlife?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, masturbation, day-of-judgement

Salam. I have a question regarding this hadith that states that masturbation causes pregnant hands in the afterlife is there any such hadith that states or supports this claim? Jazak,Allah

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the stackexchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As for your question: I guess that if there was any halfway reliable hadith on the topic of masturbation there was no discussion on the topic especially from dhahiri and hanbali side.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hadith with such a meaning:

> يجيء الناكح يده يوم القيامة ويده حبلى
>
> The one who masturbates with his hand will come on the Day of Judgement and his hand shall be pregnant
>
> <sup>— [Shu'ab al-Eemaan](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31612/5546)</sup>

It is weak.

Ref: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/21088/

Comment: So can one do tawbah and be forgiven?

Comment: I mean if he does tawbah and gets forgiven is it Possible he doesn't gets this punishment?

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult to say that a certain hadith does not exist but it is quite certain that there is no sahih or Hasan hadith like that because the teaching that masturbation is haram is only based on the interpretation of Al-Muminun [23:5-7] [1]

[1][https://tanzil.net/#trans/en.itani/23:5]