# Please answer if Allah will forgive or not

Tags: forgiveness, tawba, masturbation, day-of-judgement, hereafter

Aoa

I used to masturbate and i was addicted to it but i did a tawbah and promised never to do it again and left it Alhumdulilah but i sometimes feel i am not forgiven as i heard that there is a punishment for it in the afrerlife which is "your hands will be pregnant" is there any hadith for this? And i just sometimes feel no matter what i will still get this punishment that's why i feel i'm doomed and cannot do anything about it..are these waswasa from shaytaan?..please help me can Allah forgive me i did tawbah will Allah forgive i am so frightened by this punishment that i can't even know what's reality..please help your brother in need..jazak Allah

Comment: You have asked this question so many times. Why you are asking again and again? Please read [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70132/is-there-any-hadith-that-masturbation-will-cause-pregnant-hands-in-the-afterlife)...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you forget about this. Allah forgives all sins and you are forgiven, you did the right thing and now you shouldn't worry about that anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion my friend